# cannot declare pointer to ‘struct tm&

Tags: c++

Hey guys so I'm using gcc as my compiler. I want to pass a pointer of a struct to a function, and modify the pointer (not the content inside of if). I know I can do something like:

```
void addDate(int & *timeinfo, string &response);
```

I was trying to do this:

```
void addDate(struct tm & *timeinfo, string &response);
```

When I do that I get this error "cannot declare pointer to ‘struct tm&". How can I do this? is my only option doing a double pointer? I know that is not that bad, but I like to avoid those as much as I can.

Comment: If you want a reference to pointer, use `*&`, not `&*`.

Answer (score 2):

`struct tm` is a type.

`struct tm & timeinfo` means that timeinfo is referencing a variable of that type.

`struct tm * timeinfo` means that timeinfo is a pointer to  a variable (that may or may not exist) of that type.

`struct tm * & timeinfo` means that timeinfo is a reference to a variable (which exists) that happens to be a pointer to a variables (that may or may not exist) of type `struct tm`.

`struct tm & *` means nothing. You can't have a pointer to a reference, because the reference itself is not a variable, and pointers point to variables.

Note: when I say that "may or may not exist" I mean that the variable may or may not be allocated in memory.